# xPages calling a stored procedure

Tags: jdbc, xpages

Is there a way to call a stored proc from xPages with parameters ?

I am using @JDBCExecuteQuery("oracle",sql,params)

How am I suppose to call the stored procedure ?

What would you put in your SQL line ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot use a stored procedure with the @JDBC functions. Instead you can create a Java class/managed bean to call a stored procedure via JDBC. I have an example here how to use JDBC with the Extlib RDBMS features here: https://github.com/zeromancer1972/XPages-JDBC/blob/master/Code/Java/org/openntf/jdbc/DataConnector.java
The rules to issue a stored procedure are documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: Thanks Olivier for your answer, I will stop trying to figure out a way.  Being new in xPages and in Java and in JDBC, I watched your example and wanted to start from it, but can you tell me what is the package org.openntf.jdbc.  I am using Notes 9 with the extension library and I used the wizard plugin for Oracle connection.

Comment: The trick is to use the Extlib version from OpenNTF and not the one shipped with Domino 9.0.1. The functions are available from v04 I think. You should install the latest Extlib from OpenNTF to get the full experience with RDBMS. More information here: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-9N7CKD

If you are new to XPages, OSGi plugins and how to install them then please ask your questions in a separate thread here. I assure you will get answers right away. Though you will find many answers to that here, too.